# psql select statement fails while issuing from command line

Tags: psql

Im on the psql command line prompt and when I issue a select statement and I dont see any response..

pv is my database

```
pv-#select * from named_table
```

does not give me any result?

is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `;` at the end of your SQL statement to tell psql that you're done and that the query should now be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The query you're given is correct, but you have to give semicolon `;` at the end of the query.

Example:

```
pv-#select * from named_table ;
```

Actually, If you miss to give semicolon it doesn't show any error, instead of that it will show the secondary prompt.
So if you give semicolon, It will be execute properly.